# Ploting pie chart in django by highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I am trying to plot pie chart in django.My Django model "Results" has two filed like below:

```
+--------+------------+
| result |    date    | 
+--------+------------+
| passed | 2017-03-30 | 
| passed | 2017-02-30 | 
| passed | 2017-03-30 | 
| failed | 2017-03-30 |
| failed | 2017-03-29 |
| passed | 2017-03-29 | 
| passed | 2017-03-30 | 
-----------------------
```

I would like to count following way and show this in pie chart as total number of passed and failed value.

2017-03-30 passed-4 and failed-1
[image]

chart_test.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#chart_container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'hello'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [
          {% for cat in responses_pie %}
            [
            {{ cat.count }} 
            ],
            {% endfor %}
            ]
    }]
        });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="chart_container" style="height: 300px"></div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def chart_test(request): 
    responses_pie =  Results.objects.filter(date=date.today()).annotate(count=Count('result'))  
    return render(request,'mbr/chart_test.html',{'responses_pie': responses_pie})
```

Comment: you have to get `responses_pie`  properly, so what is the value you are getting in {{ cat.count }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use an external app (integration with Highcharts available).
I suggest to use chartkick https://github.com/mher/chartkick.py.
Just pass to the view a list of tuples and let the app render the chart.
example:

```
browser_stats = [('Chrome', 52.9), ('Firefox', 27.7), ('Opera', 1.6),
                 ('Internet Explorer', 12.6), ('Safari', 4)]
```

in your template use:

```
{% pie_chart browser_stats %}
```

here the result http://mher.github.io/chartkick.py/?type=highcharts

> Less work best performance

:)

Comment: My django web is dynamic.Value is not constant. I would like plot pie chart from mysql  database.

Comment: Is always possible to create a dynamic chart with chartkick (i know because i did for a work)
Just create the queryset for extract the desidered values like:
`yourmodel.objects.values_list('date','count')`
or extract all data and create the list of tuples needed for the app with a loop